# How can I update font map files in User mode?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

On my MiKTeX 2.9.7206 installation, the MiKTeX console has a drop down menu that lets me update font map files in Admin more, but it does not give me any option to update in User mode.  What folder must I get into to run font map files update in User mode?

Comment: Frame challenge: you probably don’t really want to update your font map files in user mode. That’s a trap. It will appear to work, but it will break your installation later.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch MiKTeX console, it proposes to switch to Administrator mode or to stay in Usermode. Choose to stay and open the same menu `Refresh font map files`.

[image]

Comment: No, not on my installation.  Mine opens with a line saying "This tool currently operates on the shared (system wide) MiKTeX configuration." and it gives no option of switching.  It does not give me that pair of links.

Comment: Are you under Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: In `...\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`, you have  `miktex-console.exe` and   `miktex-console_admin.exe`. Launch the former.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: you almost certainly do not want to update your font maps in user mode.  That’s a trap.  It will appear to work in the short term, but break your installation more and more over time.

If you’re asking this question, you have an [XY problem,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) such as, “I downloaded a custom 8-bit font and now I need to install its font map.”  The solutions to that real problem include: [adding a local directory to your installation,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) or using an OpenType or TrueType version of the font in LuaTeX.

Comment: An easier fix than that is to go to ...\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64, then miktex-console.exe and miktex-console_admin.exe as Bernard suggested in a comment.  But I still wonder if there is not just some way to reset my WinEdt so that i offers me the same console window as it offers to Bernard.