# Arrow above = symbol - Code ok in overleaf, ko in Texmaker

Tags: errors, texmaker, code, compilation-error

I have the following code which works in overleaf, but doesn't work in texmaker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,mathtools}
%*
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{\mathclap{#1}\\[0.5ex]\displaystyle\uparrow\\ ~}}{ = } }
%*
\newcommand{\equparrow}[1][1]{\stackrel{\text{\scalebox{1}[#1]{$\uparrow$}}}{=}}
\newcommand{\equparrowx}[2][1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{#2}}{\equparrow[#1]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
b&=a/c\\[-.5\baselineskip]
a&\equparrow b\\[-.5\baselineskip]
a&\equparrow[2] \frac12
\end{align*}


\[a\equparrowx{a=b/c}b\]
\[a\equparrowx[1.5]{a=b/c}b\]
\[a \equparrowx[2]{a=\frac{b}{c}} b\]
%*
\[ a\eqstackrel{b = a/c} b \]
%*

\end{document}
```

The error in the log is:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file oasy10): Font oasy10 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Datapoint: Works in MikTeX.

Comment: Hello @StevenB.Segletes do you mean that I cannot use it in Texmaker?

Comment: I don't have texmaker.  But the fact that it works in another installation perhaps indicates it is not a package deficiency, per se.  More likely, something is out of date in *your* installation, though it might be peculiar to all texmaker installs.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I remember that some time ago it worked also in texmaker on another PC

Comment: Works fine as well on TexMaker on my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `old-arrows` has been added to TeX Live on August 25, 2015.

You don't tell what version of TeX Live is used by your TeXmaker program, but judging from the error message, the package has been installed improperly: besides the `old-arrows.sty` file, also the fonts have to be installed in the expected places and map files have to be updated.

Check your file system against the list below. In particular, look for `oasy.map`.

```
package:     old-arrows
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Computer Modern old-style arrows with smaller arrowheads
longdesc:    This package provides Computer Modern old-style arrows with smaller arrowheads, associated with the usual LaTeX commands. It can be used in documents that contain other amssymb arrow characters that also have small arrowheads. It is also possible to use the usual new-style Computer Modern arrows together with the old-style ones.
installed:   Yes
revision:    42872
sizes:       doc: 981k, run: 221k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 2.0
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  font-symbol-maths font-type1
collection:  collection-fontsextra
Included files, by type:
run files:
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oabsy10.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oabsy5.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oabsy7.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy10.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy5.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy6.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy7.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy8.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/old-arrows/oasy9.afm
  texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/old-arrows/oasy.enc
  texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/old-arrows/oasy.map
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy10.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy5.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy6.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy7.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy8.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oabsy9.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy10.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy5.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy6.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy7.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy8.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/old-arrows/oasy9.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy10.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy10.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy5.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy5.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy7.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oabsy7.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy10.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy10.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy5.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy5.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy6.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy6.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy7.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy7.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy8.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy8.pfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy9.pfb
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/old-arrows/oasy9.pfm
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/old-arrows/old-arrows.sty
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/old-arrows/README details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/old-arrows/old-arrows-italian.pdf details="Package documentation (Italian)" language="it"
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/old-arrows/old-arrows-italian.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/old-arrows/old-arrows.pdf details="Package documentation"
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/old-arrows/old-arrows.tex
```

If your TeX distribution is MiKTeX, be sure to update the font maps as an administrator as well as a user. See [How can I update font map files in User mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520948/4427)

Comment: Hi @egreg thank you a lot for the explanation. I'm using Texmaker 5.0.4

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi This has nothing to do with the version of Texmaker, but with the release of TeX Live you have on the machine. Open the log file of your test and report the first line, please.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.12) 22 SEP 2021 12:14
entering extended mode

Comment: Then it is MiKTeX's fault. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve the problem is to comment the command:

```
\usepackage{old-arrows}
```